# Correct Collection to use for ordered collection

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I have a collection, That needs to be ordered in the order it is created.

But then at any time The User can change the order (ie move the 4th item to the first postion)

Is there any Collections with pre-built methods?

or should I use a SortedList.

```
Add(key++, Object);  //pseudo code
```

then to change item

```
SwapObject(int key, int SwapKey)
{
where key == value
   tempvalue = key;
   SwapKey = key;
   key = tempvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a generic `List<>` which has the `Insert` method, so you can insert an object in a given position any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `List<YourObject>` as container and implement `IComparer` for sorting.

List also provides methods for sorting, insert at a location or remove from a location